# Atmel AVR SRAM vs register

Tags: embedded, cpu-architecture

In Atmel AVR architecture, register and SRAM are in the same data memory space (for example 0x0000 till 0x001F would be registers, and 0x300 would be internal SRAM). How is that implemented? Is it the same principle as virtual memory?

Comment: I would think the similarity is greater to memory-mapped I/O, where device registers are mapped into the address space.

Answer (score 1):

It could be or they could be separate rams or they could be several separate ram blocks.   It starts in the processor core and then, esp with that core being harvard architecture, instruction fetches vs data, split into at least two busses, then you get on the data bus, and then you have some sort of address decoder to isolate peripherals from ram and perhaps registers from sram.

It may very well be that they are simply part of the generic sram.  Or it could be that they are their own bank of ram closer to the processor, but that happen to be addressable.  And that address decoding may happen in the core and not make it to the edge of the processor where the sram and peripheral decoding would happen.

If split then yes it may feel a little like virtual memory in that there is a space in one address space to maps to some other thing.  But unlike virtual memory that you dont have an mmu doing it, esp one you can reprogram or that can check permissions, etc.

This addressing registers thing is a feature in some other 8 bit processor, I am wanting to say the 8051, so the AVR may have been designed with a feature like that as well.  But like BCD math instructions, is a feature that has gone by the wayside.  Much more likely not to see it than see it.